# Read and parse files with go templating

Tags: go, hugo, go-templates, hugo-shortcode

### Context

I am looking for a nice way to loop through a **json array file** to populate a video gallery in a Hugo project. Here is the general idea of what I have in mind:

```
content/
    some_section/
        index.md  (uses {{<iframe_gallery>}})
        videos.json
    ...
```

**videos.json**

```json
[
    {
        "title": "some video",
        "url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/kjkdskdck"
    },
    {
        "title": "some other video",
        "url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/kjzflzjan"
    }
]
```

I found a lot of valuable resources about how to load and parse json files in **go** like [this one](https://tutorialedge.net/golang/parsing-json-with-golang/)

### Issue

Go and go templating are quite new for me. I don't understand how to **transpose** what I read about realizing this in plain go to go-templates. I naively started with

**iframe_gallery.html**

```
<section class="flex-ns flex-wrap justify-around center">
    {{ $jsonFile, $err := os.Open("./videos.json") }}
```

and got

```
Process: loading templates: "/home/zar3bski/Documents/Code/Sites/melainya/layouts/shortcodes/iframe_gallery.html:2:1": parse failed: template: shortcodes/iframe_gallery.html:2: too many declarations in command
```

I feel like I am missing an important difference but fail to understand it in a synthetic way. How would you load, parse and loop through this json array? Is there a more direct way to achieve this goal?

Comment: [`os.Open`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Open) is native Go code, it is not supported inside Go templates.

Comment: *"How would you load, parse and loop through this json array?"* -- Generally you would do that by writing Go, inside `.go` files, compiling it and then executing it. I have no experience with Hugo though, maybe it offers some feature that facilitates what you're looking for, maybe it doesn't.

Comment: more specifically, go templates automatically handles trailing error emitted by function calls. [The doc](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Arguments) says `Such a method must have one return value (of  any type) or two return values, the second of which is an error.`

Comment: looks like there is a more native way https://gohugo.io/templates/data-templates/